# How exactly use runProgramInGuest in Vmware CLI (Windows host, Ubuntu guest)?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, vmware, xserver

Please help me to understand how to use this command in Windows

1. Environment:

   1. Windows 10 Host with installed and running (VsXsrv X Server)
   2. Ubuntu 16.04.3 Guest
   3. Workstation 12.5

What I want:
Create a shortcut on the Windows desktop 10 with which I can start the application in Ubuntu, which will open in the window manager of Windows

How should I build such a query through vmrun?

This does not work
vmrun -T runProgramInGuest -gu guestuser  -gp guestpassword "C:\Users\andre\Documents\Virtual Machines\Ubuntu 64-bit\Ubuntu 64-bit.vmx" /usr/bin/X11/xclock -display 192.168.33.1:0

1. I can do the following:

   1. Connect to guest through putty
   2. Make export variable display by "export DISPLAY=192.168.33.1:0"
   3. Write in terminal "sudo gedit" Result

[image]

But how can this be done through vmrun ?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you are running a valid command.
See that example:

```
vmrun -T server -h https://xps:8333/sdk -u root -p mypassword -gu administrator -gp guestpaswd 
  runProgramInGuest "[Vol1] win2008-1/win2008-1.vmx" -activeWindow "c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe"
```

This example taken from [this tutorial](http://www.virtuatopia.com/index.php/How_to_Remotely_Run,_List_and_Kill_Programs_Running_in_a_VMware_Virtual_Machine)